# Logging in on VPN, how to still use Internet

Tags: windows-7, networking, vpn

I am using a VPN connection to dial up into a company's network. I just set it up in the Windows 7 connections manager, giving an IP address and my credentials.

Being situated in a rural area, they have a very slow internet connection. At the moment, all my requests I make to Internet resources are routed through the VPN connection, and the company's.

How can I make only connections to the VPN's IP range (192.168.3.xx) be routed through the connection, and all other connections use my normal DSL connection?

I am running Windows 7 on a DSL line. I am connected to that line through a router that serves as DHCP server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you go into the properties for you VPN connection, on the Network tab select IP version 4 and go into its properties. Then click the advanced button. On the IP settings tab, uncheck the "use default gateway on remote network" box.

This should default to sending connections over you DSL line, and traffic to the VPN should still work as expected.

(apologies if I've gotten some of the screen/tab names wrong there, they're based on the Vista layout!)